# $\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2=\left|2\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}\right|^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

I'm reading Complex Analysis by Stein and Shakarchi (page 13). The goal is to prove that $\partial f/\partial z=2\, \partial u/\partial z$ where $f=u+iv$ and $z=x+iy$. The proof in the book states that
$$\begin{align}\det J_F (x_0,y_0)&=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\\&=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2\\&\overset{?}{=}\left|2\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}\right|^2.\end{align}$$
I understand everything except for the last step marked with "?". What I get instead is
$$\begin{align}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2&=\frac{\partial u^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial u^2}{\partial y^2}\\&=\frac{\partial u^2\partial y^2+\partial u^2\partial x^2}{\partial x^2\partial y^2}\\&=\frac{\partial u^2(\partial x^2+\partial y^2)}{\partial x^2\partial y^2}\\&=\frac{\partial u^2\partial z^2}{\partial x^2\partial y^2}\end{align}$$
but I don't understand why should that equal $\left|2\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}\right|^2$.

Comment: Are $x,y$ functions or are they variables in themselves?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire $x,y$ are variables.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing, but partial derivatives are not fractions, so you can't treat them like fractions.

Comment: @peek-a-boo So how would you justify the last step in the book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We define
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial z} &:= \dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} - i \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)
\end{align}
So, by definition of the modulus of a complex number (and the fact that $u$ is real valued), it immediately follows that
\begin{align}
\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2 + \left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2 &= \left|2\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial z}\right|^2.
\end{align}

---

As a side note, we also define
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \overline{z}} &:= \dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} + i \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)
\end{align}
Hence, it also follows that
\begin{align}
\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2 + \left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2 &= \left|2\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial z}\right|^2 
= \left|2\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \overline{z}}\right|^2 .
\end{align}

Comment: That's exactly the part I don't understand. Could you please elaborate on "it immediately follows that"?

Comment: $-\frac{i}{2}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\implies \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2=-4\left(\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}\right)^2-\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{1}{4}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)$, how to get the desired result from that?

Comment: @BIRA If $\zeta = a+ib$, where $a,b$ are real then $|\zeta|= \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$, or equivalently, $|\zeta|^2 = a^2 + b^2$. This is just the definition of the complex modulus (geometrically, this amounts to drawing a right angled triangle, and applying pythagoras, to the triangle of side lengths $|a|$ and $|b|$ and hypotenuse $|\zeta|$). Now, put, $\zeta = 2 \frac{\partial u}{\partial z}$ and $a=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ and $b=-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$